# What api authentication method should be used for server to server communication?

Tags: api, authentication, flask, authorization, flask-restful

I have a webapp in flask where users can login with email and password. Connected to the same database I have an api where those same users will use it programmatically. When they make requests I need to know who's making the request.

I read about athentication and authorization, but I'am confused about what's the best method for my use case. I focused on JWT tokens but the expiration of the tokens makes me think it's not the best in this scenario.

How should the server login programmatically when the token expires and so on? Is there a common way to do what I pretend?

Answer (score 1):

Use jwt to auth api(i use [Flask-JWT-Extended](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/))

example:

```
def login_required(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorate(*args, **kwargs):
        verify_refresh_token()
        identify = get_jwt_identity()
        expires_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(get_raw_jwt().get('exp'))
        remaining = expires_time - datetime.now()
        # auto refresh token if token expiring soon
        refresh_space = current_app.config['JWT_MIN_REFRESH_SPACE']
       # store the token in requests.g object
        if refresh_space and remaining < refresh_space:
            g.refresh_token = create_refresh_token(identity=identify)
            g.id = identify
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorate

@login_required
def view_func():
    pass
    # return json
```

When token will expire, the func will auto refresh token, you can get new token in requests.g object and then return to user.

[quote](https://github.com/pjshu/flask-blog/blob/dc3ab167ba96f0d9a858e5658d13704913d86abb/app/app_admin/token_manager.py#L70)

[quote](https://github.com/pjshu/flask-blog/blob/dc3ab167ba96f0d9a858e5658d13704913d86abb/app/app_admin/__init__.py#L9)

Comment: In terms of security is this safer then just set a really big expiration time in the first token? If the token is stolen by someone, they can keep getting new tokens and keep logged in right?

Comment: this may help you :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508257/how-is-a-refresh-token-more-secure-than-a-long-lived-jwt  https://github.com/vimalloc/flask-jwt-extended/issues/239